# Improving BaseAdapter performance with bitmap decoding

Tags: android, performance, gridview, baseadapter

I am trying to develop an App where the user takes a picture and it is saved in the gallery. The path to that image is saved in database as a string. I have a GridView which uses an Adapter and displays image (by decoding it using Bitmap.decodeFile and BitMap.Options to match it to the ImageView size).

The problem is that, this decoding by the Adapter is taking a long time and my UI suffers lag, 'serious' lag of like 3 seconds. I need some help in optimising it.

I am doing it in Kotlin and my OptimiseImage class is as follows(followed by my getView method from the Adapter class):

```
    class OptimiseImage {
    companion object {
        fun getBitmap (iView: ImageView, imagePath: String):Bitmap {
            // Get the dimensions of the View
            val targetW = iView.getWidth()
            val targetH = iView.getHeight()

            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options() // Returns Option Object
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true // So it does not run out of memory if image is big
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions) // But can still query the size of the image
            val photoW = bmOptions.outWidth
            val photoH = bmOptions.outHeight

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            // Return the lowest out of the two based on photo orientation
            val scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH)

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor

            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions)
        }

        fun getBitmap(height:Int, width:Int, imagePath: String):Bitmap {
            // Get the dimensions of the View
            val targetW = width
            val targetH = height

            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options() // Returns Option Object
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true // So it does not run out of memory if image is big
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions) // But can still query the size of the image
            val photoW = bmOptions.outWidth
            val photoH = bmOptions.outHeight

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            // Return the lowest out of the two based on photo orientation
            val scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH)

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor

            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions)
        }
    }
}
```

Any my getView method is the following:

```
   override fun getView(i: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
    Log.d(TAG,"In getView")
    var cView = convertView
    val (_, name, company, _, imagePath) = mSitesData[i]

    if (convertView == null) {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        cView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sites_grid_layout, null)
    }
    val iView = cView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageview_cover_art) as ImageView
    val siteName = cView.findViewById(R.id.site_name) as TextView
    val siteCompany = cView.findViewById(R.id.company_name) as TextView

    if (imagePath.equals("")){
        iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera_item)
    } else {
        val image = OptimiseImage.getBitmap(165,165,imagePath) //How to avoid this slowing down the UI?
        iView.setImageBitmap(image)
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Out of GetView")
    siteName.text = name
    siteCompany.text = company
    return cView
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this manually when there's libraries like [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which do all this for you and don't cause any slowdown?

Comment: As @ianhanniballake has mentioned, libraries take the hassle out of getting involved with the decoding, they are heavily optimised and a known quantity.  However there is also nothing wrong with your question.  Think about asynchronously loading images - this will not block the UI thread. However this will introduce some extra complexity as you will only want to "publish" the result bitmap if its still needed (the view is still on screen). I suggest asynchronous loading with a callback, that can be removed if the view is scrolled out of view, you'll probably want some sort of LRU cache as well

Comment: plus one to Glide. Use it

Comment: Thanks! I can see most examples utilising Glide as Http request type or direct with Bitmap. Can anyone help me find examples with decoding bitmap please? Will I still use an Adapter or Glide can work as an adapter OR my adapter should be using glide?